# Exibir ListView com redes disponíveis

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando popular um `ListView` com o List retornado pelo método `getScanResults()` da classe `WifiManager`. No entanto, não gostaria de ter que percorrer esta lista, afinal, todas as informações que necessito já estão nela. No entanto, ao passar diretamente esta lista para este método, ele exibe todas as propriedades da classe `ScanResult` para cada item. Gostaria de poder exibir somente o SSID.

```
package tk.joaoeduardo.metropolitano;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Main extends Activity {

    private ListView list;
    private WifiManager wifi;
    private ArrayAdapter<ScanResult> adapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }

    protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart();

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ScanResult>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    }

    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        adapter.addAll(wifi.getScanResults());

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();

        list = null;

        wifi = null;

        adapter = null;

    }

}
```

Comment: Em vez de usar ArrayAdapter, você vai ter que criar uma classe de BaseAdapter e gerenciar como o ListView exibe as informações. Olha aqui por um exemplo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333754/how-to-customize-listview-using-baseadapter

Comment: Pesquisei mais sobre a classe BaseAdapter, e realmente, ela é mais interessante nesse caso que demonstrei. Mas isso depende do caso. Inicialmente tinha usado a solução do ramaral, mas ainda estou pesquisando para chegar a uma decisão - até para postar aqui o código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não vai ser possível sem percorrer a lista retornada pelo método `getScanResults`.
No código postado isso é feito no método `addAll`do adapter.
Esse método percorre a lista que lhe é passada e adiciona cada item ao array.

O que eu sugiro é criar uma `List<String>` só com o SSID obtido de `getScanResults` e passá-la ao `adapter` no `constructor`

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ssidList);
```

Em vez de ser o método `addAll`do adapter a percorrer a lista passa a seres tu a fazê-lo ao criar a lista `ssidList`

Comment: Como disse na resposta ao comentário do @bitbank, a solução usando o BaseAdapter se encaixa melhor na situação que apresentei, mas seria uma questão de gosto no final das contas. Eu me identifiquei melhor com aquela resposta, já que queria evitar mais um looping. No entanto, sua resposta também é correta.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um Adapter que herde `ArrayAdapter<ScanResult>` e nele você substitui a forma de exibir a informação sobrescrevendo o método `getView`.

Também você pode criar um `ArrayAdapter<String>` que recebe uma `List<String>` no construtor e você sobrescreve o método `getItem`.